# Proof explanation: $I_A$ is measurable$ \iff A$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-sets

We look at $I_A^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha)$

$$I_A^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha) = 
  \begin{cases}
    \mathbb{R}, & \alpha\geq1 \\
   \emptyset, & \alpha<0 \\
    A^C, & \text{for } 0 < \alpha < 1
  \end{cases}$$

So $A^C$ is measurable $\iff$ $A$ is measurable

The optional images are $\{0,1\}$ so if the image is $(-\infty,0)$ then the pre image is an empty set
Why the preimage when $0<\alpha<1$ is $A^C$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for $\alpha\geq1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse image of $(-\infty,\alpha)$ is the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}$ at which $I_A$ takes values in $(-\infty,\alpha)$  Since $I_A$ only takes the values $0$ and $1,$ if $\alpha\ge1$ this is true of every point in $\mathbb{R}.$  If $0\le\alpha<1$ the only possible value of $I_a$ in $(-\infty,\alpha)$ is $0$ which is attained precisely at the points in $A^C$.

Comment: if $\alpha\leq 1$ so we are looking at ${x:I_A(x)\leq 1}$?

Comment: @gbox We are always looking at $\{x\in\mathbb{R} | I_A(x) < \alpha\}$

Comment: Sorry, the opposite if $\alpha \geq 1$ we are looking at $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:I_A(x)\leq 1\}$

Comment: @gbox Yes, that's true.

Comment: one last thing, if the function could return any value in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha>5$ for example, so it would have been $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)<5\}$ correct?

Comment: @gbox No, that's not correct.  The only reason you can cut it off at $\alpha=1$ is because you know it can't return a value great than $1$.  Try your suggestion with $f(x) = x$ and $\alpha = 7$  Now you have $\{x\in\mathbb{R} | x<7\}=\{x\in\mathbb{R} | x<5\}$  Clearly this is false.

Answer (score 1):

- $x \in A \iff I_A(x) = 1$, so $I_A^{-1}(\{1\}) = A$
- $x \notin A \iff I_A(x) = 0$, so $I_A^{-1}(\{0\}) = A^C$

1. When $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $I_A^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha)) \supseteq I_A^{-1}(\{0\}) = A^C$.  To show the reverse set inclusion, let $I_A(x) < \alpha < 1$, so $x \notin A$ from above.
2. What $\alpha \ge 1$, $I_A^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha)) \supseteq I_A^{-1}(\{0,1\}) = \Bbb{R}$, so $I_A^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha) = \Bbb{R}$.